# Comparing a variable to a column's default value in Oracle procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, default-value

I have a table that has two columns that have a default varchar value. Also I have a stored procedure that takes in 4 values, two varchar values and two date's. I would like to compare the two input varchar values to the default values of the two columns in the table even when no rows have been inserted into the table. Is there a possible way to do this?

This doesn't work, but something along these lines.

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE TEST_PROC
(
  TEST_NAME IN VARCHAR2  
, TEST_VERSION IN VARCHAR2  
, TEST_START IN DATE  
, TEST_END IN DATE 
) AS
BEGIN

if TEST_NAME = TABLE.COL_1.DEFAULT_VALUE 
AND TEST_VERSION = TABLE.COL_2.DEFAULT_VALUE ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the data dictionary to get the default value of your columns. Then declare variables in your procedure and compare the input. Like this, for example:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME||'.'||COLUMN_NAME, DATA_DEFAULT
INTO tableVariable, defaultVariable
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME=:myTable
AND COLUMN_NAME=:myColumn
AND DATA_DEFAULT IS NOT NULL
```

You can also use it as a cursor, and loop through it.

Comment: I can't get this to work, when I put COL_1 in place of COLUMN_NAME as you have it says that it is an invalid identifier. Any ideas?

Comment: COLUMN_NAME is the column in the DATA DICTIONARY VIEW. Compare it to the column in your table. That's why I used bind variables. For instance, if the table you want to compare is TABLE_1 and your column is COL_1, it should be: WHERE TABLE_NAME='TABLE_1' and COLUMN_NAME='COL_1'